# What is the minimum/ideal memcached stack for a dedicated memcached virtual cluster

Tags: linux, memcached, centos

Currently I am considering:

VMWare Hypervisor ESXi

CentOS 5.5

Memcached 1.4.5
and dependencies

That is ALL. Is there anything else I need/any substitutions?

Comment: Maybe better suited for serverfault?

Comment: I'm not sure that running Memcached in VMs is a useful use of memory - you may as well (in many cases) just give the memory to your database server(s) instead so they can cache the DB directly.

Comment: I did not know about serverFault, thank you, I will search there.

Comment: @MarkR why not? It will work just as expected. Tons of people use huge servers with virtual nodes to deploy servers on the same hardware instance. Goal of Memcache is scalability, giving MySQL more RAM will not make it process 1% of requests that Memcache can serve.

Comment: @Aleksey: If you can keep your entire database in RAM and still have enough memory left on your database node(s) for some processing in your database, then you don't need any more. At this point it may be worthwhile setting up a few read-only replicas to scale reads. This approach doesn't need memcached, and doesn't need the major application-layer changes required to use memcached, risk of stale data, etc.

Comment: @MarkR even if you keep your MySQL/PSQL database in RAM the Memcache will scale better. Furthermore, adding more ram to database server != loading it in the memory as you originally stated. There are no risks of stale data if you properly implement caching solutions. A properly setup caching layer with a single memcache node will be faster then 10 slaves when it comes to scalability on equal hardware nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Memcached runs very well on linux, so CentOS linux is OK.
Linux CentOS runs well on VMWare, so it's OK.

Memcached 1.4.5 is quite old. Please consider installing memcached 1.4.13 (latest stable release right now).